# Upload one CSV into two diffrent tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one CSV that looks like this

```
Firstname | Lastname | EMail | CustomerNo
```

Now I have one table "Names" which is

```
id | Firstname | Lastname | ContactID
```

and a table "Contact which is

```
id | Email | CustomerNo
```

Both ids have AutoIncreatement and are connected with a foreign key.

Does anybody know how to import the CSV to Mysql, since LOAD DATA doesn´t support Joins

Comment: Upload the CSV in temp table as is and the do `insert by select` into both tables individually by `disabling the foreign key` and then issue an update command to link both tables. Then enable the `foreign key`. This is more of `ETL` question.